# Does Python subprocess of multiprocessing create a new python VM?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to create multiple **singleton** instances in Python in an unittest (to mock the multiple Python programs to interact). The singleton here is a class attribute. The class is from external library thus we could not modify the code. The code is basically

```py
class Holder:
    # this is class attribute and will have 
    # only one instance in a Python VM
    instance = None 
    @classmethod
    def getOrCreate():
        if Holder.instance is not None:
            # get
        else:
            # create
```

I think there could be only one of this instance in a single Python VM so that I want to create another Python VM to achieve this.

I have tried `multiprocessing.Process`, but when the subprocess code access this, the instance is already created, which I think the main process and subprocess are using same Python VM.

Update: I have post the minimum reproduce code in answer and I am clear for this now.

Comment: Read about the GIL.

Comment: Probably because you forked the process. It's two different processes for sure

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think they are 2 different python processes, but from the behavior they share the same python interpreter

Comment: @Litchy I recommend you keep reading, then read about multiprocessing.  But understanding the GIL is the first step in your learning on this topic.

Comment: @Litchy no, absolutely not. Again, you are probably using fork, in which case, it essentially copies the parent process, so any modifications in the parent process at the time of the fork will be visible to the child process. Try using spawn

Comment: @TomServo What does the GIL have to do with the OP's problem? It seems entirely irrelevant

Comment: In any case, you must provide a [mcve]. I highly suspect the issue I brought up is the problem. But regardless they are definitely not sharing the same VM.

Comment: Thank your for all your suggestions, I would do some search of GIL, fork/spawn and vote to close this question for now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OP's question suggests lack of familiarity with what options exist for multiprocessing in Python.  Unless memorized rote, little of it makes sense lacking understanding of how the GIL influences the design and constraints of the language.  That is why it is relevant.  It has nothing to do with copy-paste solutions, but it is relevant to understanding.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I set the start method to `spawn` and it works!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga From the Python official doc, "The parent process uses `os.fork()` to fork the Python interpreter. The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child process."  I am not clear about the description it seems that it may share something with the parent process. Anyway I wound try to reproduce with a minimal example and update.

Comment: @Litchy fork is copy-on-write. It does share memory until you write to it, which effectively with Python happens all the time because all objects carry around a reference count.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, I have updated the answer, hope it would be helpful for someone. And you could edit if there is anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer in short: Yes**, they are different VMs

Thanks for tips of @juanpa.arrivillaga

I have created a minimum reproduce example for this question.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing

class A:
    instance = None

def create_instance():
    if A.instance is None:
        A.instance = "hello"
        print("instance created")
    else:
        print("instance exists")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_instance()
    proc = Process(target=create_instance)
    proc.start()
```

Output:

```
instance created
instance exists
```

If I set `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')`  
The result becomes

```
instance created
instance created
```

However, the first output does not caused by main process and subprocess accessing the same interpreter(VM), but by the default `fork` [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) method of subprocess, it inherits the variables in main process.

To verify this we just change the order of main code to

```
    proc = Process(target=create_instance)
    proc.start()    
    create_instance()
```

And we can see the result becomes

```
instance created
instance created
```